# How can I collect the values in a multi-step form on submit?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm currently using this package to generate a multi-step form: https://github.com/Srdjan/react-multistep

I've made a number of modifications, but the one bit I'm having trouble with is figuring out how to piece all the data together for a submit. I'd like to take the values of the fields at the time of submit and use it to push a new item into a Mongo collection.

Here is an example of a form section, done as an individual component:

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

const store = { title: '', isbn: '', author: '' };

const StepOne = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState() {
    return store
},

handleTitleChanged(event) {
    store.title = event.target.value;
    this.setState(store);

},

handleIsbnChanged(event) {
    store.isbn = event.target.value;
    this.setState(store);

},
handleAuthorChanged(event) {
    store.author = event.target.value;
    this.setState(store)
},

render() {


    return (
        <div key={key}>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="six columns">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input className="u-full-width" placeholder="Title"
                           type="text"
                           onChange={this.handleTitleChanged}
                           value={this.state.title}
                           autoFocus/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="six columns">
                    <label>ISBN</label>
                    <input className="u-full-width" placeholder="ISBN"
                           type="text"
                           onChange={this.handleIsbnChanged}
                           value={this.state.isbn}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="six columns">
                    <label>Author</label>
                    <input className="u-full-width" placeholder="Author"
                           type="text"
                           onChange={this.handleAuthorChanged}
                           value={this.state.author}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )}
})

export { StepOne }
```

A number of these form step components are aggregated this way:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { StepOne } from './StepOne.jsx';
import { StepTwo } from './StepTwo.jsx';
import { StepThree } from './StepThree.jsx';



const steps =
[
    {name: 'Step one', component: <StepOne   />},
    {name: 'Step two', component: <StepTwo  />},
    {name: 'Step three', component: <StepThree  />}

];

export { steps }
```

And finally these steps are rendered in the Multi-step package I linked above.
What I'd really like to do is access that store variable in the individual form component from within the Multi-step parent component. Is there a way I can call the getInitialState method from the parent? I've tried adding a ref to the component, but because the components are placed into that "steps" const, I can't add a ref because it's not a React Owner.

I feel like this must be simple but I'm not seeing how to go about it right now. Any advice on how to submit this kind of multi-step form, where the form fields exist in separate components? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the guy who tried to help you out on reddit...
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4qw4bv/how_to_collect_multistep_form_info_on_submit/

The problem with the `react-multistep` package you link to above is that the state of each component is stored local to that component, then destroyed as you progress. I don't see how it would work (as is) in any practical sense, therefore it's not useful beyond the aesthetic.

If you love the way it looks and want to make it work, then you'll have to modify it to save the state of each component at a higher level in a common store. In this case, you'd want to capture state in the [Multistep component](https://github.com/Srdjan/react-multistep/blob/master/src/index.js).

There are a ton of forks to that package, so maybe if you look through those forks, you'll find that someone has already done this work for you.

But I'd recommend abandoning that package and instead have a look at this fairly straight forward approach...
https://www.viget.com/articles/building-a-multi-step-registration-form-with-react

Comment: Hey! Thanks a ton for the response. I feared this might be the case, but regardless I'll investigate the forks and the article you linked. Seems strange that a component designed to be a form can't actually function as a form...